# How to start table with correct output in python

Tags: python, math, logic

I'm currently new to coding Python and am struggling with a small piece of code that I can't seem to figure out. My code essentially takes in a starting salary and outputs the salary increase over the course of how ever many years the user enters and makes a table out of the output. Everything in my code is correct except for one problem. I need to start the table with the starting salary that the user enters instead it starts the table with what you would make in year 2.

```
percent = float(input("Enter the annual percent increase: "))
years = int(input("Enter the number of years: "))
percent = percent / 100
print("%-7s%10s" % ("Year","Salary"))
for i in range(1,years):
    starting += (starting * percent)
    print("%2d%17.2f" % (i, starting))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the order of the prints and the addition:

```
for i in range(1,years):
    print("%2d%17.2f" % (i, starting))
    starting += (starting * percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 starting = 1000  # sample starting

percent = float(input("Enter the annual percent increase: "))
years = int(input("Enter the number of years: "))
percent /= 100
print("%-7s%10s" % ("Year", "Salary"))
for i in range(years):

    print("%2d%17.2f" % (i, starting))
    starting += (starting * percent)
```

Will give

```
Year       Salary
 0          1000.00
 1          1030.00
 2          1060.90
```